# Centering of GridView when an UWP app is Minimized

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have this `GridView` wrapped in a `Grid`. When Full Screen, it looks good. But when I minimize it, I want the whole `GridView` to be centered within the `Grid`. In the below images (link provided), one of them is in full screen and it's ok. The other one is aligned to the left on minimizing. How can I Center them. The left and right padding is fine, but it looks ugly. Here is my `GridView` styles and panels.

```xml
<GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10, 10, 10, 10"/>
    </Style>
</GridView.ItemContainerStyle>

<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <ItemsWrapGrid x:Name="MaxItemsWrapGrid"
                       MaximumRowsOrColumns="3"
                       Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

The `GirdView` Images can be found below.

1. `GridView` in full screen - [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr4U0.png).
2. `Gridview` in Minimized view - [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEpT5.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your needs, it is recommended that you use [ItemsRepeater](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/items-repeater#uniformgridlayout) to keep the element in the center as a whole.
It is a WinUI control, you need install Microsoft.UI.Xaml in NuGet Manager.

```
  <muxc:ItemsRepeater ItemsSource="{x:Bind items}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
            <Grid Background="BlueViolet" Height="200" Width="300" Margin="10,10,10,10">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="47"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}" Foreground="White"
               FontSize="15" Grid.Column="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        
        <muxc:ItemsRepeater.Layout>
            <muxc:UniformGridLayout MinItemWidth="300"
                            MinColumnSpacing="30"
                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                            ItemsJustification="Start"/>
        </muxc:ItemsRepeater.Layout>
    </muxc:ItemsRepeater>
```

Running result:
[image: enter code here]

Comment: Good thing, I'm already using muxc in my app. This works, thanks a lot 